# Прекращение работы сервиса живых обоев libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, livewallpaper

Доброго времени суток.

Проблема состоит в том, что написанные мной живые обои с использованием libgdx довольно часто закрываются системой. Как я предполагаю это связано с убийством сервисов для освобождения памяти. Но разве у живых обоев не должно быть хотя бы более высокого приоритета? И как можно предотвратить такое?

Сами обои по максимуму оптимизированы, используют как можно меньше ресурсов и освобождают их при всех возможных паузах

AndroidLauncher класс

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidLiveWallpaperService {

@SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
@Override
public void onCreateApplication () {
    final AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useCompass = false;
    config.useWakelock = false;
    config.useAccelerometer = false;
    config.getTouchEventsForLiveWallpaper = true;
    config.useRotationVectorSensor = false;
    config.useGyroscope = false;
    //установка параметров в случае первого запуска
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(preferences.getStringSet("charecters",null) == null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Set<String> stringSet = new android.support.v4.util.ArraySet<>();
        stringSet.add("tim");
        stringSet.add("mil");
        editor.putStringSet("charecters", stringSet);
        editor.commit();
    }

    //Костыль для оптимизации
    SomeBody.charecters = getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE).getStringSet("charecters",null);

    final ApplicationListener listener = new Wallpaper();
    initialize(listener, config);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return AndroidLiveWallpaperService.START_STICKY;
}
```

}

Данный код тоже не очень помогает

`public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return AndroidLiveWallpaperService.START_STICKY;
    }`

Сам Wallpaper довольно простой

```
public class Wallpaper implements ApplicationListener,AndroidWallpaperListener {

static final float SP = 64; //маштаб


private SpriteBatch batch;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Color backgroundColor;
private Texture backgroundTexture;

private World world;
private ArrayList<SomeBody> someBodies; // Лист содержащий информацию для отрисовки объектов

@Override
public void create () {
    Preferences preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("settings");
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0),false);
    world.setContactListener(new WallpaperContactListener());
    createWorldBorder();

    someBodies = SomeBody.createSomeBodies(world);
    backgroundColor = new Color(preferences.getInteger("red",255)/255.0f,preferences.getInteger("green",255)/255.0f,preferences.getInteger("blue",255)/255.0f,1);
    if (backgroundTexture != null) backgroundTexture.dispose();
    String backString = preferences.getString("background","star1");
    if (backString.equals("color"))backgroundTexture = null;
    else backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("star1.png"));

    if(preferences.getBoolean("first",true)){
        if (backgroundTexture != null) backgroundTexture.dispose();
        backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("star1.png"));
    }

}

private void createWorldBorder(){
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(0,0);
    bodyDef.allowSleep = true;
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
    bodyDef.bullet = true;

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.restitution = 1;
    fixtureDef.friction = 1;
    fixtureDef.density = 1;
    ChainShape shape = new ChainShape();
    shape.createChain(new Vector2[]{
            new Vector2(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(SP*16)),
            new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/(SP*16),0),
            new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/SP - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/(SP*16) ,0),
            new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/SP,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(SP*16)),
            new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/SP,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/SP - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(SP*16)),
            new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/SP - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/(SP*16),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/SP),
            new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/(SP*16),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/SP),
            new Vector2(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/SP - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(SP*16)),
            new Vector2(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(SP*16))
    });
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;

    Body border = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    border.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    border.setUserData("border");
    shape.dispose();
}

private void drawColorBackground(Color color){
    if (color != null){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(color.r,color.g,color.b,color.a);
    }else {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
private void drawTextureBackground(SpriteBatch batch,Texture texture){
    if (texture == null)return;
    batch.draw(texture,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/SP,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/SP);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width/SP;
    camera.viewportHeight = height/SP;
    camera.position.set(width/(2*SP),height/(2*SP),0);
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    drawColorBackground(backgroundColor);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    drawTextureBackground(batch,backgroundTexture);
    world.step(1/Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(),8,3);
    for (SomeBody sb : someBodies) {
        if (sb.body != null) {
            if (sb.body.getPosition().x < 0 || sb.body.getPosition().y < 0 || sb.body.getPosition().x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/SP || sb.body.getPosition().y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/SP){
                world.destroyBody(sb.body);
                sb.body = null;
                continue;
            }
            sb.update();
            sb.draw(batch);
        }
    }
    batch.end();

}


@Override
public void pause() {
    for (SomeBody sb : someBodies) {
        sb.dispose();
    }
    if (batch != null) batch.dispose();
    world.dispose();
    if (backgroundTexture != null)backgroundTexture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0),false);
    world.setContactListener(new WallpaperContactListener());
    createWorldBorder();
    Preferences preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("settings");
    backgroundColor.set(preferences.getInteger("red",255)/255.0f,preferences.getInteger("green",255)/255.0f,preferences.getInteger("blue",255)/255.0f,1);


    someBodies = SomeBody.createSomeBodies(world);
    if(preferences.getBoolean("first",true)){
        if (backgroundTexture != null) backgroundTexture.dispose();
        backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("star1.png"));
    }
    if (backgroundTexture != null) backgroundTexture.dispose();
    String backString = preferences.getString("background","star1");
    if (backString.equals("color"))backgroundTexture = null;
    else backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("star1.png"));
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    if (batch != null)batch.dispose();
    for (SomeBody sb : someBodies) {
        sb.dispose();
    }
    backgroundTexture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void offsetChange(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {
}

@Override
public void previewStateChange(boolean isPreview) {

}

@Override
public void iconDropped(int x, int y) {

}
```

}

Был бы очень благодарен советам, подсказкам и ответам. Спасибо

Comment: Рекомендация: делайте на "нативе", если нужно 3D используйте OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 0):

В общем ответ крылся почти на поверхности. При полном обновлении текстур несмотря на метод dispose система выделяла сервису все больше памяти. Доходило до 1,5гб! В общем решением было немножко изменить логику обновления начинки обоев

Не нужно было постоянно создавать-очищать-создавать. Просто поработать с камерой